# Laravel 5 - Is there a way to use built-in authentication but disable registration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building an administrative back-end and thus need to hide public user registration.  It appears that if you want to use the built-in Illuminate authentication you need to add

`use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` to your controller definition.  This trait is defined [here](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.html).

It appears as if it is impossible to disable registration if you want to use the built-in auth handlers... can someone show me wrong?

Comment: The docs cover manual authentication http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

Comment: I'm aware of that.  I want to use the built-in authentication, but disable public registration.  It seems strange to me that registration and logging in are handled in the same interface.

Comment: just override the postRegister method and you should be fine ;)

Comment: Overriding the post/getRegister methods is acceptable given what I want is not natively possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Laravel 5.2+ and I found that if you remove the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` and use just `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` does the trick too.

Though `/register` is still accessible and will throw a *fatal error*.

Comment: This worked for me - I combined it with the answers above to redirect the `/register` routes, although I found I had to override `showRegistrationForm()` in `AuthController`, rather than `getRegister()`. I wish I knew why.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://slick.pl/kb/laravel/overriding-login-and-registration-functionality-in-laravel-5/) talks about overriding the auth controller. Its worth a read, at a basic level it seems you can add the following lines to app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php :

```
public function getRegister() {
    return redirect('/');
}

public function postRegister() {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

So if a user accesses the registration url it will redirect them away to a place of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own form of registration.  The only thing Laravel does is make it easy to authenticate on a users table because they create the model, build the db schema for users and provide helper methods to authenticate on that model/table.

You don't have to have a view hitting the registration page... But if you want to use the built in auth you still need to use (or set) a Model and a driver for database connections.

You can just remove that view and/or controller method from the route that links to the registration view and create your own (or seed the database manually).

But, no, you cannot forgo using Eloquent, and the User model and expect to use built in auth.  Built in authentication requires that you specify settings in /config/auth.php. You may specific a different model (other than User) and you may specify a different table, but you cannot forgo the configuration completely.

Laravel is very customizable though, so you can achieve what you are looking to do... plus why not use Eloquent, it's nice.

Answer (score 0):

*Based on @shoo's answer, working with Laravel 5.2*

Add the following lines to app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php :

```
public function showRegistrationForm() {
    return redirect('/');
}

public function register() {
    return redirect('/');
}
```